# Looking for a Simple Way to Change Default Font Sizes in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, chapters, fontsize, tocloft

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage  % Clears all blank pages
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vspace*{5pt}} 
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vspace*{7pt}} 
\cftpagenumbersoff{section}

% Dotfill for Chapters
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\dotfill}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\contentsname{{\color{red} \hfill Table of Contents \hfill}}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chap. 1. (Default Font)}
\section*{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Sec. 1.1 (Default Font)}
\chapter*{2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\LARGE Chap. 2. LARGE font.}
\section*{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\large Sec. 2.1 large font.}
\end{document}
```

which produces the Table of Contents:

[image]

It seems, that if I want a LARGE font size for Chapter entries, then `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\LARGE Chap. 2. LARGE font.}` gets the job done for a particular entry. Similarly, `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\large Sec. 2.1 large font.}` for sections. However, I have many such entries and would like to be able to do this on a global basis; and, without affecting the font sizes of the chapter and section titles within the document itself.

QUESTION: Is there a *simple* way to set the separate font sizes for all chapter, section, and subsection entries in the TOC? Are there a preamble commands, perhaps, to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: The command to change the font is described in the tocloft documentation on  page 10, the same page which describes the `\cftchapleader` and `\cftchapafterpnum` you already use.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thank you for pointing this out. I did not find these commands on the page you referred me to (maybe I'm looking at old documentation)---but going through the document, I discovered that `\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\small}` will change the section font size to small and `\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\LARGE}` the chapter font size to LARGE. Perhaps there are other ways, but this seems to work. Thank you again for posting your comment.